# For statistical resampling, why do we use Mean Squared Error (MSE) and not Residual Standard Error (RSE) to measure the test set error rate?

Tags: cross-validation, standard-error, resampling, mse

Is this as trivial as 'we use RSE for training-set and MSE for test-set'?

Comment: Why do you believe this to be true?  Do you have a source for this claim?

Comment: I was just going by my observation while reading [ISLR - Intro to Stat Learning by James-Hastie-Tibshirani](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Statistical-Learning-Applications-Statistics/dp/1461471370)